# Factorization of Schur polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

For a weakly decreasing sequence of non negative integers $\lambda = (\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_n)$ the Schur polynomial $S_\lambda$ is defined as

$S_\lambda(x_1,x_2,...x_n) = \sum_T x_1^{t_1}x_2^{t_2}...x_n^{t_n}$

Where the summation is taken over all semi standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and $t_i$ is the number of occurrences of $i$ in the tableaux.

There are two equivalent definitions, one involving the ratio of two determinants and one involving the Kostka numbers as coefficients.

What I would like to know is if there are any results about the factorization (or at least a partial factorization) of $S_\lambda$

Comment: What do you mean by "roots" in more than one variable?

Comment: Good point, I was a bit hasty on that not realizing it didn't make sense in more then one variable.

Comment: This has been discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98494/irreducibility-of-schur-polynomials , though a comment casts doubts on the accepted answer.